# Custom login and logout response in Laravel 7.x

Tags: api, authentication, create-react-app, laravel-7, custom-authentication

I am trying to login and logout from a `create-react-app` application which uses an application with Laravel 7.x as backend. Where can I put the custom response message for `/login` and `/logout` auth routes in Laravel 7.x. I used the artisan command for auth scaffolding.

I know about Single Page Application authentication in Laravel.  It is given in the Laravel Sanctum page. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum. I have followed everything there and have no problems with that.

I get redirected to `/home` route even when I have **commented** out the line in `LoginController.php`

```
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

I tried to look up the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication it says "Laravel provides an empty authenticated(Request $request, $user) method that may be overwritten if desired:".  But don't know where this method can be written.

Answer (score 1):

So I will answer my own question. This method is present in the trait `AuthenticatesUsers.php` which is present in `vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/` directory.

I added this in the empty method called `authenticated()` in `AuthenticateUsers.php` trait present in above link.

```
    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return new Response(['success' => 'you have been authenticated'], 200);
    }
```

For custom logout response, use the `loggedOut()` method in `AuthenticatesUsers.php` trait.

Hope this helps someone.  I also created a pull request in the docs repository, hope it gets accepted. Thanks.